# When __call__ override is done for enum class, code should return reference of a new instance instead of same instance to every call

Tags: class, object, enums, instance, python-3.8

I am trying to have a list which calls Enum with user-defined value.
With use of same list, we can use the reference to call get() method when required.

As per below sample code, we can see that value is getting overridden because same instance of an object is used as `return self` is used

Tried multiple approaches to create new instance instead of `return self` but couldn't get expected result.

Any suggestion? if this approach is done in some other way then also it would helpful

```
class Watch(IntEnum):
    START = 0
    STOP = 1
    def __call__(self, time=0):
        self.time = time
        return self  # this would return same instance of an object but needed to send a new instance everytime

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Time is {self.time}"

    def get(self):
        return self.time
```

**Output**

> [Watch.START(), Watch.STOP(10), Watch.START(), Watch.STOP(20)]
>
> **Expected:** [Time is 0, Time is 10, Time is 0,
> Time is 20 ]
>
> **Actual:** [Time is 20, Time is 20, Time is 20, Time is 20]

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `Enum` works.  Unlike normal classes, members are created when the class is created, and creating new members is not supported (since an `Enum` should be a limited set of predefined constants).

If you need to be creating new and arbitrary values, an enum is not what you need.

Comment: I have updated my question a little bit to give better understanding on the requirement. Exactly I am trying to have some predefined constants which can take argument. Post that one function will call get() to do required action